# methods for estimating SNR of an audio file?

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

how do I estimate SNR from a single audio file containing speech?
I know of two methods:

1. log power histogram pecentile difference (aka "NIST quick method"), described here: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/tmp/nist/doc/stnr.txt
2. 10*log10( (S-N)/N ), where

   - S = sum{x[i]^2 * e[i]}
   - N = sum{x[i]^2 * (1-e[i])}
   - e[i] some sort of voice activity detection (speech/non-speech indicator)

are there any better methods that do not require stereo data (or data in both clean and noisy version)? I also would like to avoid the "second method" described in the NIST document (see 1.) that makes strong assumptions about the distributions.

Comment: Given a single-channel, single-version audio file and no assumptions about the noise distribution, how are you going to distinguish signal and noise?

Comment: Assumptions are OK, but in the "second method" they're quite strong. Expecting speech at high energy values and noise at low energy values is fine anyway.

Comment: 2. you have to fix the weights. because for N you sum it only for silence periods and for S only for the speech periods. (now if you speech less your SNR will be different)

Comment: ok, thanks! you're right, if e[i] is a binary function, but in general, if it's defined over the whole range [0..1], the normalization terms (1/L) would cancel out, right?

Comment: @Pavel: I doubt you can create a non-binary function that will give right results. for that you already have to know the SNR.

Comment: @Pavel: I have a few ideas, but need some more details.  How accurate do you need to be and what is the application?  In some cases there may be easier tests that can be performed or some decisions can be made without inferring the SNR.  Also, it is important to sssseparate ssssibilance ("noisy" phonemes like the 's' sound -- basically noise that is part of normal speech)?  Does the background noise have any interesting characteristics or is it broadband spectral noise?

Answer (score 8):

Human voice uses frequencies from 300 Hz to 3 kHz. This is what (old) telephone systems are using. Human voice never uses all these frequencies at a time, this is why we can do a frequency analysis for finding the noise floor - without any reference or voice activity detection e[i]:

1. Compute FFT with a frequency resolution of ~ 10 - 20 Hz.
   With a samplerate of 48 kHz you would use an FFT length of samplerate/resolution = 4800 samples, which should the get rounded to the nearest power of 2, which is 4096
2. Identify the necessary bins which hold the results from 300 - 3000 Hz.
   The bin index k holds the result for frequency k*samplerate/FFT_length. For above 48 kHz input and FFT length 4096 this is  k(300 Hz) = 300 * 4096 / 48000 ~= 25 and k(3000 Hz) = 3000 * 4096 / 48000 ~= 250.
3. Calculate the energy in each necessary bin: E[k] = FFT[k].re ^2 + FFT[k].im ^2. It depends on your FFT algorithm "where" the real and imaginary parts are written.
4. N = min{ E[k=25..250] } * number_of_bins (=250-25+1)
5. S = sum{ E[k=25..250] }
6. SNR = (S-N)/N. The level is 10*log10(SNR)
7. As the SNR varies over time, go back to step 1 with some new samples - probably with some overlap